# How to run a python Trained Model in Matlab without Toolbox?

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, random-forest, numerical-integration

I have trained a random forest in python . With Matlab version 2019 , I know that  we can directly run python in matlab. I can save the python data in hdf5 format.it can also be loaded to Matlab. But I dont know how to combine the architechture with parameters in matlab and use it to predict.

The problem is : I neeed to deliver it in a matlab format without dependany on python or matlab toolbox.

I have 5 features and 1 Output. Its a Classification task.

Comment: Use basic data types in arrays and you can be pretty certain, that matlab will load it.

Comment: ok . Load into matlab so. But how do it put it back in format that it does the task of a trained random forest.? I lack the knowledge how a random forest is mathematically structured